# How to convert multiple Mongoose documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Each of my schemas have a method, called `toItem()` which converts the doc to a more verbose / human-readable form.  How can I create a `toItems()` method to do the same thing for an array of documents?

My example schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var membershipSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    m : { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'member' },
    b : { type: Date, required: true },
    e : { type: Date },
    a : { type: Boolean, required: true }
});

var accountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    n   : { type: String, trim: true },
    m   : [ membershipSchema ]
});

accountSchema.methods.toItem = function (callback) {

    var item = {
        id      : this._id.toString(),
        name    : this.n,
        members : [] 
    };

    (this.m || []).forEach(function(obj){
        item.members.push({
            id          : obj.m.toString(),
            dateBegin   : obj.b,
            dateEnd     : obj.e,
            isAdmin     : obj.a
        });
    });

    return callback(null, item);
};

var accountModel = mongoose.model('account', accountSchema);

module.exports = accountModel;
```

I've tried using statics, methods, and third-party libraries, but nothing clean works.  I would like to keep this as simple / clean as possible and have the `toItems()` function contained within my model file.

Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `toItem()` method is specific to the schema / model.  Your `toItems()` method sounds more like a utility method which can / will be used by all of your models.  If so, I would move create the `toItems()` method inside a utility file.  You would simply pass in the array of documents and the utility method would call the individual `toItem()` method on each document.

For example:

```
var async = require('async');

var toItems = function (models, callback) {

    models = models || [];
    if (models.length < 1) { return callback(); }

    var count = -1,
        items = [],
        errors = [];

    async.forEach(models, function (model, next) {
        count++;
        model.toItem(function (err, item) {
            if (err) { 
                errors.push(new Error('Error on item #' + count + ': ' + err.message)); 
                }
            else { 
                items.push(item); 
                }
            next();
        });
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err); 
        }
        if (errors.length > 0) {
            return callback(errors[0]);
        }
        return callback(null, items);
    });
};
module.exports.toItems = toItems;
```